# Place two canvases side by side in a div

Tags: html, css, chart.js

I have two canvases using chart.js that are stacking vertically, when I want them to be side by side

[image]

```
<div style="width:30%;" class="row">
    <div class="my-4 col"><canvas id="costChart"></canvas></div>
    <div class="my-4 col"><canvas id="usersChart"></canvas></div>
</div>
```

Changing the width to a small number, and changing the col-x size doesn't get them to move into the same row. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```css
canvas{
    border:1px solid red;   
}
.row{
    display: flex       
}
```

```html
<div style="width:30%;" class="row">
    <div class="my-4 col"><canvas id="costChart"></canvas></div>
    <div class="my-4 col"><canvas id="usersChart"></canvas></div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately that did not help :/

Comment: What's wrong? I suppose the problem is that your `row` is too narrow with `width30%` and the second canvas goes down.